# C program failing to append integers to vector correctly

Tags: arrays, c, vector, multidimensional-array, integer

I have a C program where I want to divide a 2D array among processes where the array work is not exactly divisible by number of processes. However, this is my small program where I compute the start x and y indices of the big 2D array that will be allocated to each process (also how many rows and columns each processes will get) and append the results to vectors. There is a problem appending elements to the vectors (I have printed out the program output for i_start and j_start vectors). I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help would be great. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  int K = 10;
  int L = 10;
  int P = 8;

  double pco = sqrt(P);
  int pcol = (int)pco;

  while((P % pcol) != 0) {
    pcol--;
  }

  int prow = P/pcol;

  int KL = K*L;

  int coldiv = K/pcol;
  int rowdiv = L/prow;

  int colrem = K % pcol;
  int rowrem = L % prow;

  int map[L][K];

  int count = 1;
  for(int i=0; i < L; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < K;j++) {
      map[i][j] = count;
      count++;
    }
  }

  int i_start[P];
  int j_start[P];
  int n_rows[P];
  int n_cols[P];

  int start;
  int num_cols = 0;
  int count1 = 0;

  // appending to vector here
  for(int j = 0; j < prow; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < pcol; i++) {
      if(i < colrem) {
        start = (i*(coldiv+i));
        num_cols = coldiv + 1;
        printf("col index start: %d\n", i*(coldiv+i));
        printf("col index finish: %d\n", i*(coldiv+i)+coldiv+1);
      }
      else {
        start = (i*coldiv+colrem);
        num_cols = coldiv;
        printf("col index start: %d\n", i*coldiv+colrem);
        printf("col index finish: %d\n", i*coldiv+colrem+coldiv);
      }
      i_start[count1] = start;
      n_cols[count1] = num_cols;
      count1++;
    }
  }

  int count2 = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < pcol; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < prow; i++) {
      int start, num_rows;
      if(i < rowrem) {
        int start = i*(rowdiv+i);
        num_rows = rowdiv + 1;
        printf("row index start: %d\n", i*(rowdiv+i));
        printf("row index finish: %d\n", i*(rowdiv+i)+rowdiv+1);
        j_start[count2] = start;
      }
      else {
        int start = i*rowdiv+rowrem;
        num_rows = rowdiv;
        printf("row index start: %d\n", i*rowdiv+rowrem);
        printf("row index finish: %d\n", i*rowdiv+rowrem+rowdiv);
        j_start[count2] = start;
      }
      n_rows[count2] = num_rows;
      count2++;
    }
  }

  // error: printing vectors
  for(int i = 0; i < P; i ++) {
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    printf("i start: %d\n",i_start[P]);
    printf("j start: %d\n",j_start[P]);
  }
}
```

Program Output:

```
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
row index start: 0
row index finish: 3
row index start: 3
row index finish: 6
row index start: 6
row index finish: 8
row index start: 8
row index finish: 10
row index start: 0
row index finish: 3
row index start: 3
row index finish: 6
row index start: 6
row index finish: 8
row index start: 8
row index finish: 10
i: 0
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 1
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 2
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 3
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 4
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 5
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 6
i start: 1
j start: 0
i: 7
i start: 1
j start: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your intentions, you are simply printing the wrong output.

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < P; i ++) {
>     printf("i: %d\n", i);
>     printf("i start: %d\n",i_start[P]);
>     printf("j start: %d\n",j_start[P]);
> }
> ```

Here, you are printing for `i_start` and `j_start` always the same index with `P` instead of `i`.

Changing to:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < P; i ++) {
     printf("i: %d\n", i);
     printf("i start: %d\n",i_start[i]);
     printf("j start: %d\n",j_start[i]);
 }
```

your output will became:

```
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
col index start: 0
col index finish: 5
col index start: 5
col index finish: 10
row index start: 0
row index finish: 3
row index start: 3
row index finish: 6
row index start: 6
row index finish: 8
row index start: 8
row index finish: 10
row index start: 0
row index finish: 3
row index start: 3
row index finish: 6
row index start: 6
row index finish: 8
row index start: 8
row index finish: 10
i: 0
i start: 0
j start: 0
i: 1
i start: 5
j start: 3
i: 2
i start: 0
j start: 6
i: 3
i start: 5
j start: 8
i: 4
i start: 0
j start: 0
i: 5
i start: 5
j start: 3
i: 6
i start: 0
j start: 6
i: 7
i start: 5
j start: 8
```